# Other Computer Science communities?

Tags: discussion

Are there any other Computer Science communities you would recommend?
So, please give me some recommendations.

Comment: That's a bit like asking "Amazon, what are other good ereaders but the Kindle?". Anyways, it would be interesting to know which of your needs we can't cover, both in order to give a helpful answer and to improve [cs.SE].

Comment: Amazon can answer that for you: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n%3A2642129011%2Ck%3Aereader+-kindle&keywords=ereader+-kindle&ie=UTF8&qid=1365939336&rnid=2941120011

Comment: Oh, they do that now? They did not use to.

Comment: There was a time when I would suggest the /r/CompSci sub-reddit, but for the past year it has been flooded with garbage. /r/Algorithms isn't so bad, it's just not that active.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso From the feedback I got to posts on [cs.SE] on either subreddit, I would not trust anything on there. For TCS, that is.

Comment: the question is a bit vague but +1 to encourage [online] cs community. one that recently popped up: [google+ cstheory community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102658328974323340942). also, a somewhat underutilized feature, one can start ones own "community" or join an existing one in stackexchange chat via existing/new chat rooms.

Comment: @Raphael it is valuable to have such a list, so that we can cross-post good questions on CS to those communities, and therefore drive traffic here => new members.

Comment: also [google+ CS](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/113263855242342230352) with 8K members

Answer (score 8):

- *Research*-level *Theoretical* Computer Science — [Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com)
- Statistics and Data Mining and some AI — [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- Artificial Intelligence — [Meta Optimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/)
- Cryptography — [Crypto - Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)
- Computation in Science and Engineering — [Computational Science - Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- Cognitive Sciences — [Cognitive Sciences - Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed most of them are on the StackExchange network. That means everything except metaoptimize. You think there aren't any other good sites other than stackexchange?

Comment: "I don't know any other good community" != "There is no other good community"

Comment: Crypto.SE is not "Applied Cryptography and Security"; Crypto.SE is for Cryptography.  For Security, see ITSecurity.SE (which you might want to add to the list).  Unfortunately, I don't have permission to suggest an edit to this answer, or I would suggest an edit myself.

Answer (score 7):

For Programming Language Theory: [Lambda-The-Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org)

Answer (score 2):

- [/r/compsci](http://reddit.com/r/compsci) on reddit,  discussion/link aggregation
- [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) on Y combinator, discussion/link aggregation
- **freenode**: irc, live discussion,questions/answers,links (irc://irc.freenode.net/)

  - `#algorithms`
  - `##computerscience`
  - `##cs`
  - `##machinelearning`
  - `#dann` (dANN project)
  - `#ai`
  - `##AGI`
- **foonetic**: irc, live discussion,questions/answers,links, (irc://irc.foonetic.net)

  - `#xkcd-cs`
  - `#xkcd-compsci`